# Check if array is a subset of another array and list all the differences at the end with an assert failure using js/chai/mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

Consider *expectedData* is the **subset array** I would like to check inside  *actualData* **array**.

I tried the following but it fails on first error. I would like to have all the differences between actual and expected arrays listed at the end of execution with an assertion failure.

```
expectedData.forEach((item) => {
  assert.deepInclude(actualData, item, 'actual data did not include item')
})
```

Example Data:

```
let expectedData = [
  {
      "val": -10.12,
      "key": "ABC"
  },
  {
      "val": 10.12,
      "key": "DEF"
  },
]


let actualData = [
  {
      "val": -10.12,
      "key": "ABC"
  },
  {
      "val": 10.12,
      "key": "DEF"
  },
  {
      "val": 9.8,
      "key": "LMN"
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you please include example data?

Comment: I've removed "JSON" from your question and tags because it's clear you're talking about arrays and objects in JavaScript and not JSON, which is a data serialization format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any built in method. For now, Used For loops to iterate through each element to compare and saved the mismatches to an output array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why I missed this when I first looked, but the code you posted has a (many?) syntax error(s). Try this:

```
let expectedData = [
  {
      "val": -10.1,
      "key": "ABC"
  },
  {
      "val": 10.12,
      "key": "DE"
      },
  {
      "val": 9.8,
      "key": "LMN"
  },
]


let actualData = [
  {
      "val": -10.12,
      "key": "ABC"
  },
  {
      "val": 10.12,
      "key": "DEF"
  },
  {
      "val": 9.8,
      "key": "LMN"
  },
  {
      "val": 1,
      "key": "XYZ"
   },
]

expectedData.forEach((item) => {
  assert.deepInclude(actualData, item, 'actual data did not include item')
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked too. I missed the syntax here as I directly typed the code in the box.  Let me correct it. I have been working with  correct syntax though!

Comment: Ok... well the code I posted is working on my end. Is there any chance you have anything else going on?

Comment: Let me the put the negative test I am trying to do. Updated the data

Comment: I would like to have all the differences listed at the end with an assertion failure. deepInclude fails at the first error

Comment: @newuser then you might have to use something other than `deepInclude()`, like your own function